# How to insert image into Microsoft Access Database?

Tags: c#, image, ms-access

I'm trying to convert images to insert into Microsoft Access Database in C#.Net Windows Form.
And also i want to delete and alter image.
But I don't know how to do that.
Please write a code segment for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd convert the image to a byte[] and. Then convert the byte[] back to an image.

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}

public static Image ImageFromByte(byte[] image)
{
    ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
    Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(image);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Yes sir.But i don't know how to convert and recovert.

Comment: I added a sample. Sorry. Using the System.Drawing namespace too.

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/c3fae255-9d2e-45e9-b830-58d544fc43ee/

Conversion will be in the following lines of the above link:

```
using ( FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead() )

                     {

                           bData = new byte[fi.Length];

                           int nReadLength = fs.Read( bData,0, (int)(fi.Length) );

                     }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\BlankDatabase.mdb"))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Create table
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            CREATE TABLE FileTable (
                FileName VARCHAR(255),
                File IMAGE)
            ";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    var imageContent = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\logo.png");

    // upload image to the table
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            INSERT INTO FileTable (FileName, File)
            VALUES (@FileName, @File)
            ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", "Logo");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", imageContent);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // retreive image from the table
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            SELECT File
            FROM FileTable
            WHERE FileName = 'Logo'
            ";
        var readImageContent = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\logo1.png", readImageContent);
    }

    // alter image from the table
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            UPDATE FileTable
            SET File = @File
            WHERE FileName = 'Logo'
            ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", imageContent);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // delete image from the table
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            DELETE FROM FileTable
            WHERE FileName = 'Logo'
            ";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

In this code `BlankDatabase.mdb` is an empty MS Access database file.

Comment: @Saya - let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes sir.I'll test it and return.